# How to send data to previous route on hardware back press react navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have 2 screens which are parent and child, I want to update the parent when I press one of the back buttons (hardware/screen header) in the child screen.

this is what I tried:

```js
export default class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    props.navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }

   componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onHardwareBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
       this.onHardwareBackPress,
    );
  }

  onHardwareBackPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.removeListener('beforeRemove');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('parentComponent',data);
  };
}
```

The react navigation 5 document says I should use `navigate` instead of `goBack/pop` to be able to set new params for my previous route.

**But** the problem with this code is when I press back in my child screen, the app gets closed (there are only these 2 screens in the stack).
Any idea what did I do wrong?